# How to set value in kendo ComboBox

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-combobox

I trying to set value for combobox, It’s correctly displayed on the page, but `options.models` doesn’t get.Can anyone help me.. Thanks a lot

```
dataSource: {
        batch: true,
        columns:{
            { field: "cluster_name", editor: myEditor},
        }
        transport: {
            create: {
                url: "127.0.0.1/create",
                dataType: "jsonp",
            }
            paramterMap: function(options, operation){

                if (operation == "create"){
                    console.log(options.models) ;// no value 
                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function myEditor(container, options){
    .appendTo(container)
    $('<input name="' + options.field +'"/>')
    .kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField : "id",
        dataValueField: "name",
        dataSource: [
            { "id": "yes", "name": "yes"},
            {"id": "no", "name": "no"}
        ]
    })
}

    var combox = $('#mygrid').data("kendoComboBox");
    combox.value("yes"); //page is correctly, options.models doesn't get.
```

Comment: Try correcting `paramterMap` to `parameterMap`. If this doesn&amp;#39;t solve your problem, can you please explain further what you mean by "`options.models` doesn't get", and make sure you post correct code; there are other errors besides the one I pointed out.

Comment: sorry,my English is not very well. After I triggered the creat event, the “cluster_name” is nothing. like this “cluster_name”:””.